# Pass List to ScraPy Spider in Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to scrape information on music artists from ethniccelebs.com. I want to pass a list of artists to a Spider that I created but it's not returning what I need.

**Here's the Spider:**

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class EthnicCelebSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    """Scrapes ethnic celebs website using XPath selector"""
    name = "ethnic_celebs"

    def __init__(self, artist='', **kwargs):
        """Takes artist as an argument when called"""
        self.start_urls.append([f'https://ethnicelebs.com/{artist}'])
        
    def parse(self, response):
        """Get artist race"""    
        races=[]
        if response.status != 404:
            next_page = response.xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/section/div[2]/article/div/div[2]/div[1]/p[4]/strong/text()').get()
            # Find word and exclude
            string_start = next_page.find("Ethnicity: ") + len("Ethnicity: ")
            races.append(next_page[string_start:len(next_page)])
        else:
            races.append('Unknown')
        
        print('\n'+race+'\n')
        return race
```

It finds the string "Ethnicity: " and saves whatever follows it.

**Here's where I call it:**

```py
# Setup scraper
process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36' 
})

# Instantiate class and pass artist
crawler = process.create_crawler(EthnicCelebSpider)
process.crawl(crawler, artist='21-savage')
process.start()

stats_obj = crawler.stats
stats_dict = crawler.stats.get_stats()

stats_dict
```

**Here's the result:**

```
{'log_count/INFO': 3}
```

I'm running this in a Jupyter notebook on Python 3.7.5 64-bit in Ubuntu 20.04. This problem persists when running outside of Jupyter.

If anyone has any pointers it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: “This problem persists when running outside of Jupyter.” In that case, it may be better to simplify the question, and about any mention of Jupyter, as it seems irrelevant.

Comment: Scrapy usually exports items to a file, according to the `FEEDS` setting. It seems you want to access items from an in-memory variable instead, in which case you will need to implement an item pipeline that does that. Your current code is simply not storing the scraped data anywhere.